# Как добавить в сборку записи из MANIFEST.MF jar-библиотеки

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle

Добавил jar-ник как библиотеку и он в своём коде пытается получить значение из манифеста. Но при сборке файлы MANIFEST.MF из библиотек игнорируются и нужной записи там нет.
Как это обойти?
Если нельзя включить в сборку эти записи, то есть мысль использовать кастомный класс-лодырь, но не знаю как сказать грэдлу добавить этот файл в сборку с другим именим/путём?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение: нужно добавить packagingOptions merge в build.gradle

```
android {
...
    packagingOptions {
        merge "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
    }
...
```